# If $x^2$ is even, why does $x$ necessarily have to be even as well?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

If $x^2$ is even, why does $x$ necessarily have to be even as well?

Comment: Depends do you consider $\sqrt{2}$ even?

Comment: @kingW3 Considering the context ("discrete", "even", "odd"), I'm assuming $x$ is an integer.

Comment: @StackTD Sure,you're right,maybe it was kinda harsh but still thinking this question needs a bit more context.

Comment: @kingW3 Agreed!

Comment: @Adriana  I encouraged the user who helped you through comments below [your most recent question,](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228239/discrete-math-questions-checking-my-answers) to post it as an answer.  It would be great if you could also upvote and accept the answer from Nunya, since you have expressed great appreciation for Nunya's help in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: suppose $x$ is odd, then $x=2y+1$ for some integer $y$; now square $x=2y+1$.

Hoover over for the next step:

> Then $(2y+1)^2 = 4y^2+4y+1 = 2(2y^2+2y)+1 = 2z+1$, so...

Writing this up nicely is what is called a [proof by contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive).

Comment: thank you this definitely explains! i was confused on how to go about it

Comment: I'd suggest adding that $x= 2y+1$ for some **integer** $y$.  And likewise, $(2y+1)^2 = 2z+ 1$ for some **integer** $ z$.  For Adriana, it is a proof by contrapositive because you are asked to prove $x^2$ even implies $x$ is even.  This is equivalent to proving  $x$ odd implies $x^2$ is odd.  That is, if you need to prove $p\to q$, you can prove $\lnot q \to \lnot p$, which is logically equivalent to $(p \to q)$

Answer (score 0):

Because it is the contrapositive of:

If $x$ is odd, then $x^2$ is odd

which you can clearly see is true.