# Discrete Math Questions? (checking my answers)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

1.Assume $a$ and $b$ are irrational numbers. Find a counterexample showing that it is possible $a-b$ is rational.

- My answer: Suppose $a$ and $b$ are equal to $\sqrt{2}$.  Therefore, $a-b= \sqrt{2}- \sqrt{2}=0$.  This proof by counterexample that $a$ and $b$ are irrational but $a-b$ is rational?...(is this correct)?

2.If $x+1$ is odd, prove that $(x+1)^3$ is odd.

- My answer: let $x+1$ be odd therefore $x+1=2k+1$ for some integer $k$.
  Suppose $x+1$ is not odd. Then $x=2k$ where 
  \begin{align}
  (x+1)^3 & = x^3+3x^2+3x+1\\  
          & = (2k)^3+3(2k)^2+3(2k)+1\\
          & = 2(4k^2+6k^2+3k)+1\\
          & = 2(a)+1 
  \end{align}
  for some integer $a$ where $a=4k^2+6k^2+3k$.  Therefore, this proves that $(x+1)^3=2a+1$ is odd.

Comment: Part 1 is correct ($a = \sqrt{2}$ and $b = \sqrt{2}$ are good choices). For Part 2, you said that $x+1 = 2k + 1$ for some integer $k$. That means $x = 2k$. Can you use this to prove that $(x+1)^3$ is odd? (That is, can you prove that $(x+1)^3$ is of the form $2m + 1$ for some integer $m$? What that integer $m$ is will need to be determined.)

Comment: You are trying to prove an implication $P \to Q$, where $P$ is "$x+1$ is odd" and $Q$ is "$(x+1)^3$ is odd". You don't go about proving this by assuming "not $P$".

Comment: @Nunya ah okay! thank you- I see my mistake I went about it thinking x=2k+1, so now I can delete the " x+1 is not odd then..."

Comment: @Nunya Thank you soooo much! For taking the time to further explain.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: @Nunya Your work here would make a fine answer to this question: (1)it is clear your work in the comments have helped Adriana to  answer the question.  (2) We like to have questions answered. (3)  I'd prefer to have **you** answer the question in an answer post, than have someone else take advantage of your work, to post your answer as theirs.  Please ping me if/when you post your answer (all you need to do is copy and paste your comments, formatting, to an answer from you), so I can upvote it.

Comment: @amWhy I copied my answer. Thank you for suggesting to me that I post it as an answer. I appreciate the upvote.

Comment: My pleasure, @Nunya!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Done.

**2.** Suppose $x+1$ is odd. Then $x+1=2k+1$ for some integer $k$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}[t]
(x+1)^3 
= (2k+1)^3 
&= (2k)^3+3(2k)^2+3(2k)+1\\ 
&= 8k^3+12k^2+6k+1\\
&= 2(4k^3+6k^2+3k)+1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, $(x+1)^3=2m+1$, where $m$ is the integer $4k^3+6k^2+3k$, so $(x+1)^3$ is odd. Therefore, we have shown that if $x+1$ is odd, then $(x+1)^3$ is odd.

Comment: Great answer, because you took note of the OP's skill level and, I think, really helped him!

Comment: @Vincent  ... really helped **him**  or **her**! :-)

Comment: @amWhy Ah, of course. You see, I am both German and tired ;)

Comment: @Vincent Thank you, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Vincent  I'm only half German, but I'm tired too! $\ddot \smile$